Weird, possibly European movie where couple inherit house and elderly housemaid from voyeur neighbour
I've been looking for this movie for many years now, with no success.
I've seen it in Europe on public TV about 10-15 years ago.
The plot:
A young couple live in a small flat of a tenement building. They have a creepy, peeping neighbour on the opposite side of the street. The neighbour dies, and they find out he left them the whole building he used to live in. They move in. The building also came with a weird woman, a maid - older German(?) women who later is revealed to be a dominatrix.
The movie might, but not necessarily must, be French, and it takes place in France or similar European country.
Does that ring a bell to anyone?
